# If $f(x) = x^4 − 32x^2 + 1,$ find the interval on which $f $ is concave up / down.

Tags: calculus

$f$ is increasing $(-8,0)\cup(8,\infty)$
and $f$ is decreasing $(-\infty,-8)\cup(0,8)$

Find the local minimum and maximum values of $f.$
local minimum $-8$
and local maximum $0.$

Am I right?

Also, can someone explain why some would say that the graph to the right is decreasing in value, when obviously it is gaining value?

[image]

Comment: Can you please use latex for your maths text.. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Decreasing in $(-\infty,4]$, then increasing up to $x=0$, then decreasing up to $x=4$, then increasing.

Comment: See [this](http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CCEQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sosmath.com%2Fcalculus%2Fdiff%2Fder15%2Fder15.html&ei=FFkjVaKZFJLl8AWGm4HwCA&usg=AFQjCNGzdVwSTnQdEFDAMPF20CYOHd_qCQ&bvm=bv.89947451,d.dGc) and [this.](http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CCoQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FConcave_function&ei=FFkjVaKZFJLl8AWGm4HwCA&usg=AFQjCNF3E2WVt2Z-vggIh5dbwV-ms3H5Tg&bvm=bv.89947451,d.dGc)

Comment: how did you get 4?

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I think that for the second part of your question, the confusion is that the derivative of f is strictly decreasing, so subsequently f is strictly concave downwards.

Comment: How is it decreasing it goes up and then goes down left to right.

Comment: In the right-hand graph, $f'(-2) = 1$ but $f'(0)=0$. That is, going from $x=-2$ to $x=0$ (left to right), $f'$ decreased, unless you think that a change from $1$ to $0$ is an _increase_. (Several of the $m$ values in the diagrams are incorrect, but if you replace them with correct values the $m$ are still decreasing under the right-hand diagram.)

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is two questions, or three, or four. In any case the last part (asking about the displayed graphs) is certainly a separate question from the rest of it.

Answer (score 2):

I want to start with he second problem, with the picture.

the first derivative gives you the rate of change for a function. Therefore, the second derivative gives you the rate of change of the rate of change, if that makes sense.

Let's analyze what this means. The rate of change of a function is the slope, so the second derivative analyzes the rate at which the slope of a function changes.

Let's look back at the picture. In the first graph, the slope is gradually increasing. Imagine drawing slope lines at every integer, and then you could see this. In the second graph, the slope is decreasing.

IN summary:

**Concave down = slope of function decreasing = negative second derivative**

**Concave up = slope of function increasing = positive second derivative**

The first problem you would do best to sketch out, starting at negative infinity and going to positive infinity. This would demonstrate that the local minima are -8 and 8 and the local maximum is at 0. This is demonstrated by the extreme value theorem.

Comment: "In the second graph, the slope is decreasing" I still do not see how the slope is decreasing. If I were to find the derivative at every point they would be gradually increasing as I went left to right.

Comment: Here (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zse4gisz4v) is a desmos model showing the function and it's first two derivatives. The red function is the original function. The blue function shows the slope of the function at any given x value.Notice that the blue line is decreasing. The blue line represents the slope. Thus the slope is decreasing.

Comment: What I find amazing is that no one was able to answer my question

Comment: The slope (m) decreases at each point... you can see the slope by drawing lines tangent to the points or graph

Answer (score 1):

Since $$f(x)=x^4-32 x^2+1,$$ we can find $$\frac{d^2f(x)}{dx^2}=12 x^2-64.$$ Then we have  $\frac{d^2f(x)}{dx^2}>0$ when $x<-\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}$ and $ x>\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}$ which means we have two minimum values in these regions. Further, we have  $\frac{d^2f(x)}{dx^2}<0$ when $-\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}<x<\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}$ which means we have one maximum value in this region.

Now you can find those values by using $$\frac{df(x)}{dx}=-64 x + 4 x^3=0$$ which gives $x=-4,~0,~4$. Thus we can say that we have minimums at $x=-4,~4$ and maximum at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ f(x)=x^4-32x^2+1 $$
First note that
$$ \frac{d}{dx}f(x)=4x^3-64x $$
$$ \frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x)=12x^2-64 $$
So now let's check for inflection points
$$ \frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x) =0 $$
$$ 12x^2-64  =0 $$
$$ 12x^2  =64 $$
$$ x^2  =\frac{64}{12} =\frac{16}{3}$$
$$ x  =\pm\sqrt{\frac{16}{3}}= \pm\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}} $$
This implies that
$$ \frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x) \gt 0\ \mbox{on}\ \left(-\infty, -\frac{4}{\sqrt3}\right)$$
$$ \frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x) \lt 0\ \mbox{on}\ \left(-\frac{4}{\sqrt3}, \frac{4}{\sqrt3} \right)$$
$$ \frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x) \gt 0\ \mbox{on}\ \left(\frac{4}{\sqrt3}, \infty\right)$$
Therefore 
$$ f(x)\ \mbox{is concave up on}\ \left(-\infty, -\frac{4}{\sqrt3}\right)$$
$$ f(x)\ \mbox{is concave down on}\ \left(-\frac{4}{\sqrt3}, \frac{4}{\sqrt3} \right)$$
$$ f(x)\ \mbox{is concave up on}\ \left(\frac{4}{\sqrt3}, \infty\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Since Frey has already addressed the minimum and maximum values for the function, I will address the last question of yours.

> Also, can someone explain why some would say that the graph to the right is decreasing in value, when obviously it is gaining value?

First off, no one would say it is decreasing in value and end it there (unless one has a fundamental flaw in their conception of a functions value).  It is increasing for $x <0$ and decreasing when $x>0 $.
Next, the little comment in blue next to the graph is not talking about the $value$ of the function, it is talking about the $slope$ of the function.  The $slope$ or rate of change of the function pictured in that second graph is $decreasing$ on the entire interval.  One can see this by, instead of looking at the value of the function at each point as you move left to right, look at the slope of the function as we go left to right.  We can see that when x is very far to the left (large and negative), that the slope is large and positive.  As we move our eyes to the right, we see that the slope is starting to flatten out.  This means its headed towards a zero slope from a positive and large slope.  So clearly, the slope is decreasing.  Next, as we pass $x=0$ the slope turns negative and gets larger and larger (negatively) as we move to the right in $x$ values.  Again, it is decreasing.  I'll say this again, the value of the function is not decreasing on the whole interval.  Instead, the $slope$ of the function is decreasing on the whole interval.

You need to train your brain to get into slope mode.  It's a way of looking at the graph.  Instead of just seeing values for the functions, you need to keep in mind that at every $x$ value we can also see the slope of the tangent line at that point and that the slope of the line gives us the value of the derivative at that point.

Answer (score 0):

> $f$ is increasing $(−8,0)\cup(8,\infty)$ and $f$ is decreasing $(−\infty,−8)\cup(0,8)$

No, $f$ is decreasing at $-6$ and increasing at $6$, for example.
Also, merely knowing where $f$ is increasing or decreasing does not tell
you where $f$ is concave upward or downward, as the title of your question asked. You can be increasing but concave downward or increasing but concave upward.

> Find the local minimum and maximum values of $f$. local minimum $−8$ and local maximum $0.$

No, $-8$ is not a local minimum. Also, there are two local minimums.

> Also, can someone explain why some would say that the graph to the right is decreasing in value, when obviously it is gaining value?

I have not seen anyone claim that the graph is decreasing in *value*. 
Clearly the function $f(x)$ presented in the graph 
(which is not the $f$ from your title) is increasing
in value when $x < 0$. What the text above the graph says is that the *derivative* of $f$, namely, $f'$ is decreasing.
And indeed you have a positive slope (that is, $f'(x) > 0$) for $x < 0$,
zero slope at $x = 0$, and negative slope for $x > 0$.
From positive to zero to negative is a decrease.

The reason why you're "not getting an answer" to your question may
be that the last part of your question shows a fundamental misinterpretation
of the mathematical language of the displayed graph.
And this is distracting from the other parts of your question.
(Actually I think you *have* gotten answers to every part of your question,
just not all at the same time, since the question has several very
different parts.)